# How to split a text file into two arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing

I am parsing a text file that looks like this:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL

MNOP
QRST
UVWX
```

Is it possible to parse this in Perl in a way which results in two 4x3 arrays? So for example,  `array1[2][2] = K` `and array2[0][1] = N`.
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

open(FH, '<', 'gwas.txt') or die "Couldn't open file $!";

while(<FH>) {

    #parse file into 2 arrays
}
close(FH);
```

Comment: Is this a puzzle?  What kind of a counting system has `K` with indices `(2,4)`, and `N` with `(1,0)`?  Can you explain? But first -- can you show us what you did and what problem you have with that?  Questions here are expected to be about _your code_.

Comment: @zdim my mistake! just fixed those and added the code.

Comment: That's better, thank you  (Still, I think you mean `a[2][2] == K` ...?)  As for the code: you make multidimensional structures by having a data structure carry _references_ to another in each slot.  Reading on references: tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and a cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  You want array-of-arrays, in `pelrdsc`

Comment: @zdim Jesus hahaha, yes that is what I mean

Comment: So, as you read the file: in the first slot of an array (row 1) put an arrayref -- a reference to an array with elements of that row. The second element of that array is a reference to an array with letters from the next row, etc. So, go line by line. Break each into letters `(my @line = split '', $_)`, put a reference to that array in the element of the "main" array for that line. (For example, `$a[$cnt] = \@line` where `$cnt` starts from zero, or so.) Etc. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure explained in a comment, condensed

```
my @matrix = map { [ split '', $_ ]  } <$fh>;
```

The *diamond operator* `<>` in the [list context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) returns all lines (see [I/O operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)), whereby each is processed by the block in [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and the returned list is assigned to `@matrix`.

In the block [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) breaks each line ([`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)) into characters (`''`), and an [anonymous array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Making-References) is made of that list (`[...]`).  Given `split`'s defaults this can be written as `map { [ split '' ] }`.

Always use *lexical filehandles*, it's better that way

```
my $file = 'gwas.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Couldn't open $file: $!";
```

---

As pointed out in comments, this processes the whole file into one array.  To process two blocks of text, each into its own array, we can write it as a loop (and use empty lines to distinguish blocks).

```
my @matrix;
my $index = 0;    
while (<$fh>) {
    $matrix[$index++] = [ split '', $_ ];
}
```

This makes an *anonymous array* `[ ... ]` with line elements and assigns it to `$index` spot in the array `@matrix` (and increments index).  Another way of doing this is

```
my @row = split '', $_;
$matrix[$index++] = \@row;
```

where a new array is constructed on every iteration and a reference to it assigned.

Then we need to use empty lines to tell blocks apart. We also need to manage the two arrays, what is nicely done by having references to arrays (matrices) in another data structure, say an array.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my $matrices;  # will be an arrayref, for references to matrices

my $file = 'matrices.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @matrix;
my $index = 0;   
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    if (/^\s*$/) {                     # blank line, done with one matrix
        $index = 0;                    # reset index
        push @$matrices, [ @matrix ];  # store anonymous array for @matrix
    }
    else {
        @matrix[$index] = [ split '', $_ ];
        ++$index;
    }
}
push @$matrices, [ @matrix ];          # the last one in the file

close $fh;

print "Spot check: \$matrices->[0][2][2]: $matrices->[0][2][2]\n";
dd($matrices);
```

This holds assumptions about the data, in general that it has the exact expected format.

Please see the tutorial on references [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and a cookbook on data strucures [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Also see the [answer by xxfelixxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43383092/4653379), with all this in a very slightly different way.

There are a number of other ways to do this.

Comment: Okay awesome, that makes sense. But my intention was to have two separate arrays, this currently only has one.

Comment: @KyleWeise Oh, I see now what you mean by two arrays.  You are right -- this would store both blocks of text into one, with a mess on empty line.  It was meant as a basic demonstration. For your whole problem write it out as a loop, as outlined in that comment.  When you hit an empty line, start with the second array.

Comment: I'm a little confused by " the above should be written out as a loop over lines with explicit assignments to each array element, and the empty line can be used to start the next block. " Could you perhaps word this differently?

Comment: @KyleWeise  Added a full program to the answer, thank you for the comment.

Comment: So I'm playing around with this and something strange is happening. The print statement works for `matrices->[0][2][2]` , but not when I switch the 0's to 1's. So the 0's give me K, which is correct, but if I replace them, shouldn't the output be W ?

Comment: @KyleWeise  Yes it should, by all means.  Apparently I forgot to copy the line -- _after_ the loop we need to add to `$matrices` the last matrix computed. Fixed.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split the data into an array of paragraphs.
2. Split every paragraph into an array of lines.
3. Split every line into an array of characters.

This can be achieved using the either following:

```
my @arrays;
{
   local $/ = "";  # Paragraph mode
   @arrays = map { [ map { [ split // ] } split /\n/ ] } <>;
}
```

or

```
my @arrays;
{
   local $/ = "";  # Paragraph mode
   push @arrays, [ map { [ split // ] } split /\n/ ] while <>;
}
```

They produce:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ],
            [ 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' ],
            [ 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L' ]
          ],
          [
            [ 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' ],
            [ 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' ],
            [ 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X' ]
          ]
        ];
```

So,

```
say $arrays[0][2][2];  # K
say $arrays[1][0][1];  # N
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems very straightforward. Can you explain the reason by the open/closed curly brackets? Are they associated with the declaration of `@arrays` or is there another meaning?

Comment: They are part of [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)'s `map BLOCK LIST` syntax.

Comment: Could you almost include how you printed the output? I assume `Data::Dumper` because of the format.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $arrays = [];
my $count = 0;
my $row = 0;

# Read data and store in $arrays
while(<DATA>) {
    if (my ($letters) = m/^(\w+)\s*$/) {
        # Store letters
        $arrays->[$count]->[$row] = [ split //, $letters ];
        $row++;
    } else {
        # Next batch
        $count++;
        $row = 0;
    }
}

# Print it out with indices
for my $iarray ( 0 .. $count ) {
    print "------ Matrix $iarray ------\n";
    my @rows = @{ $arrays->[$iarray] };
    for my $irow ( 0 .. $#rows) {
        my @cols = @{ $rows[$irow] };
        for my $icol ( 0 .. $#cols ) {
            print "($irow,$icol) -> " . $cols[$icol] . "\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL

MNOP
QRST
UVWX
```

**output**

```
------ Matrix 0 ------
(0,0) -> A
(0,1) -> B
(0,2) -> C
(0,3) -> D
(1,0) -> E
(1,1) -> F
(1,2) -> G
(1,3) -> H
(2,0) -> I
(2,1) -> J
(2,2) -> K
(2,3) -> L
------ Matrix 1 ------
(0,0) -> M
(0,1) -> N
(0,2) -> O
(0,3) -> P
(1,0) -> Q
(1,1) -> R
(1,2) -> S
(1,3) -> T
(2,0) -> U
(2,1) -> V
(2,2) -> W
(2,3) -> X
```